# Custom function for looking up tags

Tags: f#, vim

Can I hook into the mechanism that Vim uses to look up a definition when I press Ctrl+]? The documentation seems to assume that I have a tags file set up. I'd like to provide something like: given a line and column in the current buffer, fetch the word there, and return file name, line and column where that word is defined.

By way of background, I'm adding to the Vim F# plugin. I have working omnicompletion and balloons via omnifunc and balloonexpr, and now I'd like Ctrl+] to work in F# source files.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the most straightforward and solid solution would probably be to [add F# support to ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/EXTENDING.html).

In the mean time, you could use `:vim` to search an arbitrary path recursively for `<cword>` and open the quickfix window with `:copen`.

Comment: What information does a ctags parser need to return? Parsing (and understanding) F# is somewhat more complicated than the languages mentioned on that page, but I already have a helper app that keeps a typed parse tree in memory, complete with source file and line information.

Comment: This will be of no use: ctags doesn't *understand* a language. The example is only an example, it's up to you to come up with a parser based on these informations.

Comment: Extremely hacky ctags for F# - doesn't get everything: `--langdef=f#
--langmap=f#:.fs
--regex-f#=/let[ \t]*([[:print:]]*)[ ]*=/\1//
`

Comment: Yeah. There's no pre-backed solution. If you want ctags to work with `$language` you'll have to do the hard work yourself, there's no way around that.

Answer (score 0):

You could overload the `<C-]>` mapping locally in buffers with an *F#* filetype and call your own lookup function, but that would be only a partial and hacky solution, because it ignores all other tag-related functionality (like `:tag`, etc.) Better integrate into the (extensible and open) tags system.

You need to implement the generation of a *tags database* for F# source code. The format is simple, see `:help tags-file-format`. The default tags program, *Exuberant Ctags* can be extended with regular expressions, but that probably only yields an approximate parsing for a complex language like F#. Better write a dedicated executable for it. (There are precedents, like *jtags* for Java, and many of the *tag sidebar* plugins can be configured to use a custom tags program, too.)